# Insert text after tabs

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

I am trying to make a small script, and I would like to write a few lines of a file below. I try to write the output of these commands to the fstab file, to automate the assembly ... The problem is that after writing the output of the UUID of the disk, I want to write the data that is after the echo with a tabulator in each space, but I can not put them in any way ... Thank you

```html
blkid |grep "/dev/sdb"|cut -d " " -f2 |sed 's/"//g'|echo "/mnt/discon1     ext4     defaults     0       2">>fstab.bak
```

The output of the command sends it to the fstab file and passes it to me in the following way

```html
UUID=377055f4-4f83-4326-8b43-a65694de84da
/mnt/discon1             ext4              defaults         0         2
```

I need after the UUID insert a tabulator and I add the rest of the text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So many ways to parse text.

Assuming this command produces the following output:

```
$ blkid
UUID=377055f4-4f83-4326-8b43-a65694de84da
/mnt/discon1             ext4              defaults         0         2
```

We could use awk:

```
$ blkid | awk -F= '$1=="UUID"{u=$2;next} {print u,$0}' OFS="\t"
377055f4-4f83-4326-8b43-a65694de84da    /mnt/discon1             ext4              defaults         0         2
```

This sets `=` as a field separator in order to capture the UUID, but for lines without a UUID it'll print the last-captured-UUID along with the current line.

Or sed:

```
$ blkid | sed -ne $'/UUID=/{s///;h;};H;x;s/\\n/\t/;$p'
377055f4-4f83-4326-8b43-a65694de84da    /mnt/discon1             ext4              defaults         0         2
```

This searches for a UUID line, strips the left-hand-side from it and stores it in sed's "hold buffer". Then for other lines, it simply appends the current line to the hold buffer, swaps it back to the pattern buffer and replaces the newline with a tab. Then at the end of the file, it prints.

Note that the options above use a tab as the *first* separator, but copy the remaining line verbatim.

Perhaps you want something in bash alone:

```
$ while IFS== read -r a b; do if [[ $a = UUID ]]; then printf '%s' "$b"; else c=($a); printf '\t%s' "${c[@]}"; fi; done < <(blkid); echo
377055f4-4f83-4326-8b43-a65694de84da    /mnt/discon1    ext4    defaults    0   2
```

Like the awk script, this uses the `=` character as a field separator in order to capture the UUID. When it finds a UUID, it prints it. If it doesn't find a UUID, it goes through each field and prints it with a preceding tab.

Many many ways to do anything. Pick the one that you think will make the most sense to you a year from now. Try anything you're doing with data that doesn't quite match what you expect. It's important to be able to predict errors.

Answer (score 0):

Break your command into 2 lines: capture the output of blkid into a variable, then echo that variable together with the other text e.g.

```
blkid=`blkid | grep "/dev/sdb" | cut -d " " -f2 | sed 's/"//g'`
echo "$blkid /mnt/discon1     ext4     defaults     0       2" >> fstab.bak
```

Comment: Yes, wait next time for more answers.
This one could be better written as `blkid=$(blkid | grep "/dev/sdb" | cut -d " " -f2 | sed 's/"//g')` or avoid the temporary variable with
echo "$(blkid | grep "/dev/sdb" | cut -d " " -f2 | sed 's/"//g') /mnt/.....`

Comment: `cut` and `sed` can be combined with `cut -d'"' -f2` (after the `-d` a double quote inside single quotes).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed` for a lot of things. When you have time left, look at the command beneath:

```
/sbin/blkid | sed -n '/dev.sda3/ s#UUID="\([^"]*\)#\1\t/mnt/discon1\text4\tdefaults\t0\t2#p'
```

Comment: for this, I need to think so much :O thank you so much, 
you helped me a lot, I write down to examine the options